# Python search text file, print characters following a string

Tags: python, string

I want to be able to search a document for a given string and find the context for each instance.  For example, search a document for "Figure" and return X characters following that string (returns "-1 Super awesome figure" from "Figure-1 Super awesome figure. next sentence.")

I know how to print either: A) each instance of that string

```
mystring = "Figure"
with open('./mytext.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if mystring in line:
            print(mystring)
```

but that's no help; or B) each line containing that string

```
for line in open('./mytext.txt', "r"):
    if "Figure" in line:
        print(line)
```

which returns all of the text in the entire line, before and after, which is cumbersome for my purposes.

Can I split a line at "mystring" and return X characters following the split?  Or is there altogether a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it like:

```
WANTED = 20 #or however many characters you want after 'Figure'

with open('mytext.txt') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        left,sep,right = line.partition('Figure')
        if sep: # True iff 'Figure' in line
            print(right[:WANTED])
```

see: [`str.partition`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and it works great.  I'm sure other methods will return similar results, but this I understand.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
line = "Figure-1 Super awesome figure. next sentence."

search_line = line.split("Figure")

print search_line

# prints ['', '-1 Super awesome figure. next sentence.']

count = 0
for elem in search_line: 
    count += len(elem)

print count # how many chars after "Figure"
```